# jQuery understanding - Fire validate on tabbing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Trying my hand with jQuery. I have this strange situation that i wish to understand. The below script "works", only problem is not exactly the way i want it to.

Currently on page load. If i click on one of the input fields and without entering anything, tab to the next field (i.e press the tab key and go to next field), the validation is not fired. So essentially i can hit two tabs and click the submit button. This goes through (will get caught server side,but kind of defeats the purpose).

If i enter something and then delete it though, it fires the validation and even shows the message correctly.

My questions:

- How do i get the validations to fire as soon as i "exit" the field, meaning if i click inside or get into the field through a tab, and then "leave/exit" that form field, the validation should be fired.
- What's the deal with getting the validation to fire on submit? do i have to put an onSubmit or is there a event handler sort of thingy for validations (this i believe can be solved with a little more intense googling and api reading), but would you be so kind :) ?

  ```
  <style type="text/css">
    .style3 {font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #0099CC; }
    form{margin:0;}
  .error {
      font: normal 10px arial;
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 3px;
      background-color: #ffc;
      border: 1px solid #c00;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  // jQuery validation
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#advanceValidateform").validate(); 
  }); 
  </script> 


    <form id="advanceValidateform" name="advanceValidateform" style="margin:0"  action="">     
      <input type="text" id="advanceAmt1" name="advanceAmt1" class="required"  /> <br />
      <input type="text" id="advanceAmt2" name="advanceAmt2" class="required"  /> <br />
      <input type="text" id="advanceAmt3" name="advanceAmt3" class="required"  /> <br />
  </form>

  <table width="100%" class="hr-table">
      <tr height="1">
          <td colspan="4" align="center" >
              <form action="#" method="POST" >
                  <input type="hidden" name="empno" value="9999" ></input>
                  <input name="submit" type="submit" title="submit the form" value="  Submit and Print  "></input>
              </form>
          </td>
              </tr>
  </table>
  ```

Comment: Can I ask how code looks with "tab" event? I have similar problem I need to valid all fields after push tab key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply tab through it the .change() event is not fired. IF you wish to force this, you can capture the .focus() and use .trigger() to fire the change event.

Comment: Mark, I suppose blur() is what i'm probably looking for?

The code that I have pasted here however works oddly. It validates only one of the fields and then doesn't validate anything else. 

Anyone with suggestions or corrections from having a brief look at the code?

Thanks
K

Comment: from the documents regarding the validation plug-in: "Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages - he won't get bugged before he had the chance to actually enter a correct value 
" So, you will have to do something "extra" to get it to fire on empty fields before the submit.  I am NOT sure about the multiple forms and how that impacts.

Comment: So i suppose the implementation behavior was meant to be like that. Anyway thanks for pointing it out clearly.